# SQL to find a user which doesn't have a particular property

Tags: sql, join, self

From the following table, want to query a user which doesn't have 'beta_user' or 'beta_redirect' property, but has any other property.

```
UserID     | Property
-----------|-----------
user 1     | beta_member
user 1     | beta_redirect
user 1     | member
user 2     | beta_member
user 2     | member
user 3     | beta_redirect
user 3     | member
user 4     | member
```

I want to get only user 4 as output.

Answer (score 1):

You need `Group By` and `Having` Clause

```
select UserID 
from Yourtable
Group by UserID 
Having Count(case when  Property in ('beta_user' ,'beta_redirect' ) then 1 end) = 0
```

Another approach using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   Yourtable a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Yourtable b
                   WHERE  a.UserID = b.UserID
                          AND b.Property IN ( 'beta_user', 'beta_redirect' ))
```

**Note :** Even `user 2` does not have `'beta_user'` or `'beta_redirect'` property

Comment: This was helpful. Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `not in` as well, like -

```
SELECT *
FROM   <table-name>
WHERE  UserID not in (SELECT UserID       
                   FROM   <table-name>
                   WHERE  Property IN ( 'beta_user', 'beta_redirect' ))
```

Comment: We need to keep in mind that `NOT IN` will fail when there is any `NULL` value present in `UserID` column.

Comment: That's why I always use `NOT EXISTS` instead - it's "null safe"!

Comment: This was helpful.